# Is there an $x$ that can solve for this vector?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm trying to find an $x$ that solves for this:$$\left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}x\\x\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}2\\1\end{matrix}\right]$$ But I'm not sure there is. But I think there are problems that depend on the answer of this problem.

Comment: Only if $x$ can equal $1$ and $-1$ at the same time.

Comment: Curiousity, why are you trying to find such an x? From what problem is this coming from? And the fact that no such x exist, what does that mean?

Comment: It's a problem that the students I'm tutoring are trying to solve in their text book. There are more questions to follow which made me think twice about whether there was a solution or not.. My initial instinct was no there can't be. But the next few problems sounded like there was an x and that I just missed something.

Comment: Could you give one of the problems you think that there was a solution?

Comment: @copper.hat -- any minute now, someone will post an answer about some exotic algebraic structure in which $x$ **can** equal $1$ and $-1$ at the same time. Of course, this will be of no use at all to the OP.

Comment: Sorry everyone I failed to also look at the problems ahead of time to see what the problems were, and they actually did not depend on the answer. It was a case of getting too ahead and too excited to help on a subject I haven't seen in a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about vector addition. Then $1+x=2$ implies $x=1$. However, $2+1 = 3 \neq 1$. So no, it is not possible.

Comment: To whomever voted the two answers down, why? Both are well-written, mathematically correct and address the question asked. I reserve downvotes for answers that are either patently wrong or incomprehensible.

Comment: +1 for the content of the message plus correct usage of "whomever". :-)

Answer (score 4):

If there would be a $x$ which will solve this equation the following equations must be satisfied:
$1+x = 2$ and $2+x=1$. Can you find such an $x$?

Comment: Why the downvotes for the answers?

Comment: I was writing a similar comment when you posted yours. I agree completely.